# A simple query about control validators in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, validation, comparevalidator

I'm using the following Compare Validator :

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"  ErrorMessage="None can't be selected!" 
                    Operator="NotEqual" ValueToCompare="None"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

over the following Dropdown List:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="181px">
                    <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Here's what happens : Initially, nothing happens, and 'None' is selected by default. If I choose any other option and THEN choose 'None', it give me the error.

What I want to do is have the validator display the error right away when the page is first loaded, and not wait for the user to change to some other option and back over to 'None' or wait for the user to submit the form before displaying the form again.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried calling the client side validation logic right when the page loads? Using Page_ClientValidate(), for example. You could do that with jquery on ready() or registering it at startup server side.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your scenario, I think you have to set  `Operator="Equal"`, If value is "None" then error will occur "None can't be selected!".

Comment: No. That would be the reverse. The error message is displayed only when the text value is NOT EQUAL to None.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
}
```

Works in my simple test page.